# Log4j2 не работает после деплоя tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, log4j2

Ситуация следующая: Для логирования использую `log4j2` в связке с `slf4j`. Проект деплою на `tomcat8`. Конфигурация програмная(без xml)

Проблема следующая: В тестах логирование работает: файлы создаются, в консоль все пишется. После деплоя во время работы приложения на сервере логирование(ни в файл ни в консоль) не работает(используется стандартное).

Думал проблема с правами, но дело не в них(на всякий случай выдал права 777).

В `web-app` тоже на всякий случай закидывал свой конфиг, но ничего не изменилось.

Конфигурационный файл log4j:

```
@Plugin(name = "Log4j2Config", category = "ConfigurationFactory")
@Order(0)
public class Log4j2Config extends ConfigurationFactory {

    private static final String NAME_ROLLING_FILE = "com.bla";
    private static final String NAME_CONSOLE = "Console";

    private static final String PATTERN_LAYOUT = "%d [%t]  %-5level %logger{36}: %msg%n";
    private static final String PATH = "Documents/tomcat/logs/socialNetLogs/";
    private static final String LOG_FILE_NAME = "socialNet.log";
    private static final String LOG_FILE_NAME_PATTERN = "socialNet-%d{dd-MM-yyyy}-%i.log";

    @Override
    public Configuration getConfiguration(final LoggerContext loggerContext, final ConfigurationSource source) {
        return getConfiguration(loggerContext, source.toString(), null);
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration getConfiguration(final LoggerContext loggerContext, final String name, final URI configLocation) {
        return new Log4jConfiguration();
    }


    @Override
    protected String[] getSupportedTypes() {
        return new String[]{"*"};
    }

    private static class Log4jConfiguration extends DefaultConfiguration {

        public Log4jConfiguration() {
            super.doConfigure();

            initAppenderLogger(getRollingFileAppender(NAME_ROLLING_FILE), getLogger(NAME_ROLLING_FILE, Level.DEBUG), Level.DEBUG, NAME_ROLLING_FILE);

            initAppenderLogger(getConsoleAppender(NAME_CONSOLE), getLogger(NAME_CONSOLE,  Level.DEBUG), Level.DEBUG, NAME_CONSOLE);

            initAppenderLogger(getConsoleAppender(getRootLogger().getName()), getRootLogger(), Level.ERROR, getRootLogger().getName());



        }

        private void initAppenderLogger(Appender appender, LoggerConfig loggerConfig, Level level, String loggerName) {
            appender.start();
            addAppender(appender);
            addLogger(loggerName, loggerConfig);
            getLogger(loggerName).addAppender(appender, level, null);
            System.out.println("success" + getLogger(loggerName).getName() + appender.getName());
        }

        private Appender getRollingFileAppender(String appenderName) {

            final TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy timeBasedTriggeringPolicy = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy.newBuilder()
                    .withInterval(1)
                    .withModulate(true)
                    .build();

            String oneMB = "1 M";
            final SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy sizeBasedTriggeringPolicy = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy(oneMB);
            final CompositeTriggeringPolicy policy = CompositeTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy(timeBasedTriggeringPolicy,
                    sizeBasedTriggeringPolicy);
            final DefaultRolloverStrategy rolloverStrategy = DefaultRolloverStrategy.newBuilder()
                    .withMax("14")
                    .withMin("1")
                    .withFileIndex("max")
                    .withConfig(this)
                    .withCompressionLevelStr(Deflater.NO_COMPRESSION + "")
                    .build();


            System.out.println("in rolling file");

            return RollingFileAppender.newBuilder()
                    .withName(appenderName)
                    .withAdvertise(Boolean.parseBoolean(null))
                    .withAdvertiseUri(null)
                    .withAppend(true)
                    .withBufferedIo(true)
                    .withBufferSize(8192)
                    .withLayout(PatternLayout.newBuilder()
                            .withPattern(PATTERN_LAYOUT)
                            .withConfiguration(this)
                            .build())
                    .withPolicy(policy)
                    .withStrategy(rolloverStrategy)
                    .withFilePattern(PATH + LOG_FILE_NAME_PATTERN)
                    .withFileName(PATH + LOG_FILE_NAME)
                    .build();
        }

        private Appender getConsoleAppender(String appenderName) {
            return ConsoleAppender.newBuilder()
                    .withName(appenderName)
                    .withLayout(
                            PatternLayout.newBuilder()
                                    .withPattern(PATTERN_LAYOUT)
                                    .withConfiguration(this)
                                    .build())
                    .build();

        }

        private LoggerConfig getLogger(String loggerName, Level level) {
            //System.out.println("in logger for rolling");
            return LoggerConfig.createLogger(false, level,
                    loggerName, null, new AppenderRef[]{}, null, this, null);
        }

    }
}
```

В мавене все зависимости проставлены

Структура проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Класс конфигурации точно инициализируется(добавил внутрь несколько SOUT)

Работаю на Mac OS(на всякий случай ибо причину ищу очень долго)

Comment: ошибки в логе томката есть?

Comment: нет, никаких ошибок нету.  В логах все чисто